# Contagem de ocorrências em uma String

Tags: javascript

Como escrevo uma função que recebe uma [string](/questions/tagged/string) como argumento, e retorna um objecto listando o número de ocorrências na string actual ?

Actualmente tenho isto:

```
charCount("hello");
// {
//  "h": 1,
//  "e": 1,
//  "l": 2,
//  "o": 1
// }

//It should ignore capitalization

charCount("AaBbC")
// {
//  "a": 2,
//  "b": 2,
//  "c": 1,
// }
```

Comment: O que você já conseguiu fazer até agora? Edite a questão e coloque o código para podermos te ajudar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os passos que precisas que a função faça:

- separe a string em pedaços
- crie um objeto
- atribua ao objeto uma propriedade para cada letra
- conte quantas ocorrências

Essa função podia ser assim (coloquei opcional contar ou não com letras grandes/pequenas, por defeito não contando):

```
function charCount(str, keepCase) {
    if (!keepCase) str = str.toLowerCase();
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (!obj[str[i]]) obj[str[i]] = 0;
        obj[str[i]]++;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

e testando seria:

```
var a = charCount("hello");
var b = charCount("AaBbC");
var c = charCount("AaBbC", true); // contando com letras grandes!

console.log(a, b); // Object {h: 1, e: 1, l: 2, o: 1} Object {a: 2, b: 2, c: 1}
console.log(c); // Object {A: 1, a: 1, B: 1, b: 1, C: 1}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/hexn3twf/

Answer (score 3):

Consulte as funções do projeto PHP.JS

É um projeto que traduz funções do PHP para o JavaScript.

No PHP existe a função [count_chars](http://php.net/count_chars), a qual está traduzida em JavaScript no site do projeto: http://phpjs.org/functions/count_chars/

Para ver o resultado do snippet, abra o console do browser. No Google Chrome, pressione  CTRL+SHIFT+I

```js
function count_chars(str, mode) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/count_chars/
  // original by: Ates Goral (http://magnetiq.com)
  // improved by: Jack
  // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //    input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //  revised by: Theriault
  //   example 1: count_chars("Hello World!", 3);
  //   returns 1: " !HWdelor"
  //   example 2: count_chars("Hello World!", 1);
  //   returns 2: {32:1,33:1,72:1,87:1,100:1,101:1,108:3,111:2,114:1}

  var result = {},
    resultArr = [],
    i;

  str = ('' + str)
    .split('')
    .sort()
    .join('')
    .match(/(.)\1*/g);

  if ((mode & 1) == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i != 256; i++) {
      result[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  if (mode === 2 || mode === 4) {

    for (i = 0; i != str.length; i += 1) {
      delete result[str[i].charCodeAt(0)];
    }
    for (i in result) {
      result[i] = (mode === 4) ? String.fromCharCode(i) : 0;
    }

  } else if (mode === 3) {

    for (i = 0; i != str.length; i += 1) {
      result[i] = str[i].slice(0, 1);
    }

  } else {

    for (i = 0; i != str.length; i += 1) {
      result[str[i].charCodeAt(0)] = str[i].length;
    }

  }
  if (mode < 3) {
    return result;
  }

  for (i in result) {
    resultArr.push(result[i]);
  }
  return resultArr.join('');
}


/**
Exemplo de uso
*/
var rs = count_chars('foo bar', 1);

/**
O resultado retorna o valor em "bytecode", por isso, é preciso converter para o caracter correspondente. 
Aqui usamos String.fromCharCode()
*/
for (var k in rs) {
    console.log(k, String.fromCharCode(k), rs[k]);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Criei uma função que retorna o maximo de ocorrencias de um caractere em uma string e chamei de `count()`, após isto declarei um for percorrendo toda a string e pegando o maximo de ocorrencias de cada uma, nisto surgiu o problema de repetir informações de caracteres, e para resolver este problema criei um objeto que é o retorno da função para pegar todas as ocorrencias e não repeti-las, veja como ficou:

Exemplo:

```js
var str = 'Hello World';

function charCount(str) {

  function count(string, char) {
    var re = new RegExp(char, "gi");
    return string.match(re).length;
  }

  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result[str[i]] = count(str, str[i]);
  }

  return result;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(charCount(str)));
```