# String em javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Como sabe o numero de vezes que uma letra apareceu em uma frase em Javascript?

Exemplo:

```
palavra = "a"

frase = "Agora vai!"
```

Como mostra no console a quantidade de vezes que a `string` "a" apareceu na frase "Agora vai!" ?

Comment: se fez algum exemplo de código? já ouviu dizer que uma texto é um `array` de letra, ou seja, cada palavra de um texto tem uma posição?

Comment: [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103520/112052) tem algumas soluções, é só adaptar pro seu caso

Answer (score 1):

A forma braça é ler cada posição dessa `string` e verificar a correspondência, exemplo:

```js
var test = 'a';
var texto = "stackoverflow pt-brasil";
var busca = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
  if (texto.charAt(i) === test) {
    busca++;
  }
}
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = `Encontrou: ${busca}`;
console.log(busca);
```

```html
<div>
  <div><b>Texto:</b> stackoverflow pt-brasil</div>
  <div><b>Palavra de Busca:</b> a</div>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</div>
```

Se utilizar o método `match` com `regex` simplifica bem o código:

```js
// busca todos com a letra 'a' independente de ser maiúsculo ou minúscula  
var test = /a/g; 

var texto = "stackoverflow pt-brasil";
var busca = texto.match(test);

document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = `Encontrado: ${busca.length}`;
console.log(busca.length);
```

```html
<div>
  <div><b>Texto:</b> stackoverflow pt-brasil</div>
  <div><b>Palavra de Busca:</b> a</div>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</div>
```

essa segunda forma traz um `array` com todas as correspondências.

Outra forma também `for of`:

```js
// busca todos com a letra 'a' independente de ser maiúsculo ou minúscula  
var test = 'a'; 
var texto = "stackoverflow pt-brasil";
var count = 0;

for(l of texto) {
  if (l === test) {
    count++;
  }
}

document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = `Encontrado: ${count}`;
console.log(count);
```

```html
<div>
  <div><b>Texto:</b> stackoverflow pt-brasil</div>
  <div><b>Palavra de Busca:</b> a</div>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</div>
```

[Outros exemplos no próprio site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103520/contagem-de-ocorr%C3%AAncias-em-uma-string)

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu fiz a edição, obrigado.